# Strange iframes added in wordpress 4.1 localhost

Tags: html

I have a strange iframes added in my code, that you can see in the images below. I disabled all the plugins but this iframes still appeared. I tried to track where this code is in the project, but no result. I am on localhost which is strage too. Any idea how to remove this iframes. They make couple requests and try to load 412.html. In the request preview is this url cloudfront.net, I don't know if it matters. Thank you very much!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FD6Q.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4yks.jpg

Comment: It doesn't sound like it is related to WordPress. More than likely you have some adware on your machine that causes that to be injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a WordPress issue. A Google search for `boostsaves.com` reveals it is a browser add-on that injects iframes into the page source of whatever you're viewing.

Use Google to find instructions on how to remove it from whatever browser you're using.